# How to change foreground color for SVG images in WPF and c#

Tags: c#, wpf, svg, bitmap

We are trying to get bitmap from SVG but its not giving the exact co-ordinate to change the pixel color.Can anyone help me how to change the color for bitmap pixel/svg pixel in wpf.

```
WpfDrawingSettings wpfDrawingSettings = new WpfDrawingSettings { IncludeRuntime = false, TextAsGeometry = false, OptimizePath = true };
        StreamSvgConverter converter = new StreamSvgConverter(wpfDrawingSettings);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        converter.Convert(str, ms);


        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.StreamSource = ms;
        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmap.EndInit();
```

Comment: Why would you get the bitmap of a SVG? When you use bitmap they lose their ability to scale without the loss of quality. Also if you do this in xaml you can apply style to a `Path` to change the `Fill` Property.

Comment: SVG we are using can have other structure(line,polygon etc) than path so its not always necessary to use **fill** property to set the color.